# Telerik Reporting Q3 2012 Paging

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, telerik-reporting

Is there a way to handle the page next or previous event in Telerik Reporting Q3 2013?

I have a large data to load in report . Is it possible to load data partially 
    when page changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to do it programmatically. There is no out of the box solution. If you are using a table item this problem occurs. Do not use table item to load large data. Go through report wizard and assign data source to report. You can use the following links: 
•   http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-page-layout-rendering-understanding-pagination.html
•   http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-life-cycle.html